# SSRS 2008 R2 Trend Line Expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

[image: Sample Image]

Hi everyone! I want to ask something. Currently I am creating report that has a Line chart that has to determine the performance trend for every month. So my question is, Please refer to image attached. I have a `Total` column as you can see. I just create an `Expression` for `Total` column base on the Average of the of TAT per month. So I want to have Trend line for the Column `TOtal` but this is only an expression I cant add it on `Chart Series`.
Is it possible to add something like the image attached?

Thanks if anyone can help!

Comment: You could have googled this one: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3432/add-a-linear-trendline-to-a-graph-in-sql-server-reporting-services/

Comment: @R.Richards I already read about adding `Calculated Series` But the problem is my report builder has no function for Adding Calculated series.

Comment: Really? What version of Report Builder are you using? Usually, you add a calculated series by clicking on the chart until the Chart Data panes shows, and then click the plus (+) sign on the Values bar. Then add your expression there.

Comment: @R.Richards currently I am using Report Builder 3.0. I did click on the Values bar but it has `Add Calculated Series` Field their.

Comment: It should have Expression, though. Put your calculated expression there.